# pretty print in mongo shell not working - MongoDB 2.6 + Yosemite + ZSH

Tags: mongodb, zsh, osx-yosemite, pretty-print, oh-my-zsh

I'm running the mongo shell by invoking `mongo` at the command line.  The result is a bland shell experience.  I would like to see colored JSON output, etc.  I tried running:

```
> db.my_collection.find().pretty()
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried adding the following line to `~/.mongorc.js`:

```
DBQuery.prototype._prettyShell=true
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [MongoDB shell enhancement](http://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/). You can make particular tweaks after you clone the repo.